# Grep for regex in basename but return wholename

Tags: linux, bash, grep, regular-expression, posix

So say I have a list of files in a text file:

```
...
/foo/barfoo
/bar/foo/foobar
/foobar/bar/foo
...
```

I have a script that will search through this text file and, much like the locate command, I want to be able to search for the basename of the file. Thus far I've used this grep command `grep -E */.*${1}[^/]*$` which works fine UNLESS I want to grep for a regex. So, in the above example if I wanted to find files starting with "foo", I'd execute `myscript --basename ^foo` however this fails because the whole regex becomes `grep -E */.*^foo[^/]*$` which would, obviously, fail. I thought about using xargs to plug each entry into basename but I need the script to put out the whole file path at the end.

Any ideas? I'd prefer POSIX compliance but GNUisms are fine too

Comment: Show your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: I said files beginning with foo (in the basename) so:

    /bar/foo/ **foo**bar

    /foobar/bar/ **foo**

Comment: Well, sure, but are you not also looking for a way to pattern the pattern?

Comment: Yes. In the above example, I don't want it to return "barfoo". This is one example though. I want to be able to apply any of the regex symbols to the basename of a file and return the wholename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `foo` must match at the start of the basename:

```
< inputfile grep '/foo[^/]*$'
```

- `/foo[^/]*$`: matches a `/foo` string followed by any number of any character not `/` at the end of the string

if `foo` can match anywhere in the basename:

```
< inputfile grep 'foo[^/]*$'
```

- `foo[^/]*$`: matches a `foo` string followed by any number of any character not `/` at the end of the string

Comment: It does also match it anywhere in the basename - like after stuff - but i think that's what is desired here.

Comment: Wait no. In the above example it doesn't print the apropriate results.

Comment: @mikeserv Good point, I made a distinction.

Comment: @mikeserv `grep -e '/foo[^/]*$' -e '^foo[^/]*$'`

Comment: @Costas - That's what i meant by what is looked for. If a second parameter were used as a rep count rather than the kleene star, the asker could anchor the thing at head or tail or not at all with just a pattern and a number.

Comment: I only want basenames that begin with foo. So I run `myscript --basename '^foo'` and nothing returns because when the $1 is substituted in the regex becomes '^foo^[/]*$' which returns nothing

Comment: @user12061 Ok so stop using ^ and start using /foo

Comment: @user120161 You stated "I wanted to find files starting with "foo"". If this is what you want, the first command will do it, it will print only paths whose basename starts with `foo`.

Comment: @user120161 Ok I see, so as mikeserv said just pass `foo` instead of `^foo`.

Comment: you might want to recommend an optional 2cd param. Like: `"$1[^/]${2:-0,}}$"`

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions) :

```
$ grep -Po '.*/\Kfoo[^/]*$' file.txt 
foobar
foo
```

- `.*/` will match upto the last `/` and `\K` will discard the match
- `foo[^/]*$` will find the filenames starting with `foo`